# A Sincere Nurikabe Puzzle

Tags: grid-deduction

*So here's a standard Nurikabe puzzle.

I'll be using the final (solved) grid for my upcoming local puzzle competition logo as it will spell the abbreviation of the competition name. **So, what does it spell?***

[image]

> **Rules (adapted from [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/nurikabe.html))**:
>
> 1. Fill in the cells under the following rules.
> 2. You cannot fill in cells containing numbers.
> 3. A number tells the number of continuous white cells. Each area of white cells contains only one number in it and they are separated by black cells.
> 4. The black cells are linked to be a continuous wall.
> 5. Black cells cannot be linked to be 2x2 square or larger.

---

<sup>*Addendum: moving 10 up by one tile to make this unique (previously, there are 2 possible solutions as @edderiofer said).*</sup>

Comment: nice puzzle +1! can you tell me how you made it a unique solution? i mean, how do you generate one? how can you deduce the logic? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Well, actually it's not easy to make it unique (as you may see, I did the mistake to let it had multiple solutions lol). One thing for sure is we generate it as we solve it. Put some numbers, then do try to solve it till we are not sure what's next step (missing clue). After that, put another clue in a specific position such that, we can continue to solve the puzzle after the given clue... and so on until we solve all the cells. The main challenge is to make sure it has a nice pattern (for this one, for example, is the spelling) and yeah it takes time, but it's so fulfilling! XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

> Unfortunately, said puzzle has multiple solutions. Specifically, in the image below, either the cyan cells can be shaded, or the magenta cells can be shaded. Either produces a valid solution to the Nurikabe:[image]
>  It seems to me like the intended solution was for the magenta cells to be shaded, forming the answer **KPK**.

## Update:

> With the 10 clue moved, the solution is now unique. [image]

Comment: oh no, I missed that one (and the tester also missed this).. nevertheless, yep you got the right answer!