# Quick Slitherlink Puzzles: KPK and 123

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

[image]

> **Slitherlink** (taken from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/slitherlink.html))
>
> - Connect adjacent dots with vertical or horizontal lines to make a single loop.
> - The numbers indicate how many lines surround it, while empty cells may be surrounded by any number of lines.
> - The loop never crosses itself and never branches off.

---

<sup>*[KPK](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86494/28719) is an on-going local puzzle competition, authored by me.*</sup>

Comment: By on-going I mean not this particular puzzle but the overall competitions. The sub-contest including this puzzle has already been over, so feel free to answer~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer:

> [image: slither1]

The solution (KPK already solved by Omega Krypton but imma add my thought process here still):

> Let's solve KPK first. Corners can be deduced.
>  [image: slither2]
>  If we assume that blue lines are correct, then it would lead to contradictions (green lines).
>  [image: slither3]
>  Therefore it will lead to this:
>  [image: slither4]
>  Extending the blue lines vertically would lead to another pair of contradictions (green lines):
>  [image: slither5]
>  So it instead becomes this E-like shape:
>  [image: slither6]
>  Closing off top and extending green line leads to contradiction (pink line):
>  [image: slither7]
>  And so it is solved:
>  [image: slither8]
>  Now the 123. We can deduce the 3's:
>  [image: slither9]
>  Now I admit that I underwent a long period of trial and error for this one. Eventually I realized that a horizontal line of symmetry of the loop cannot exist, and so I reconfigured everything and the answer at the top is what I arrived at.

Comment: Correct, well done! :D

Answer (score 4):

Finished the KPK one, answer here

> [image]