# Spiral Stumper Series: Kurodoko

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sub>***Spiral Stumper Series*** is a $5$-puzzles series taken from the Final Round of a local (national) contest, [KPK](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86494/28719), which has been ended recently and authored by me. The theme is spiral and each puzzle is standalone (there will be no meta, etc.)</sub>

---

[image]

> **Kurodoko** (taken from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/where_is_black_cells.html))
>
> - Colour cells black according to the following rules.
> - The numbers on the board show the number of white cells from the number to the nearest black cell or to the frame of the board (horizontal + vertical).
> - The cells with numbers cannot be black, they are and remain white.
> - Black cells cannot touch horizontally or vertically, and all white cells must be connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:

> If two numbers are adjacent, and one of them is *n* bigger than the other, then the bigger number must extend at least *n* in the perpendicular direction. (For example, take the 12 and 7 in the top middle: there can only be up to 7 cells in that horizontal group, so there must be at least 5 more extending vertically from the 12.) Applying this logic in a few places gets us this far:
>
>  [image]

This deduction can be extended:

> If any method of extending n cells in the given direction would overlap something less than n, then you can't extend that many cells. For example, the horizontal group of white cells including the 8 and 10 at the bottom *cannot* be at least 7 cells: it would run into either the 4 or the 6. So it is at most 6 cells wide, and the 8 extends 2 cells upwards.
>
>  The same logic can be applied in a few other places.
>
>  [image]

Now we can start shading cells:

> The 10 and the 6 on the left are finished, so they can be blocked off. The remaining cell in the fifth column can also be shaded.
>
>  The 12 in the upper left then has only one way to extend, and that finishes the 7s along the top, and then *that* finishes the 4 in the upper right.
>
>  [image]

Now, some more cells have to extend some amount in given directions:

> The 6s on the right wall must go up at least four cells: that finishes it, as well as the 7 in the same column. Since the bottom right is shaded, the other 6 must go all the way left.
>  The 13 in the upper left needs to go down some amount, and that finishes it.
>
>  [image]

And now the rest of the puzzle can be easily resolved.

> The entire fourth row can be resolved from the 9 in it; the bottom left can be resolved with the two 4s; and the remaining cells are determined from the 9 in the eighth row.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Yup, correct, well done!