# Spiral Stumper Series: Fillomino

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sub>***Spiral Stumper Series*** is a $5$-puzzles series taken from the Final Round of a local (national) contest, [KPK](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86494/28719), which has been ended recently and authored by me. The theme is spiral and each puzzle is standalone (there will be no meta, etc.)</sub>

---

[image]

> **Fillomino** (taken from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/fillomino.html))
>
> - Fill in all empty cells with numbers under the following rules.
> - Divide all of the board into blocks. Fill each block with the same number horizontally or vertically.
> - Each block contains as many cells as the number in the block.
> - Same sized blocks cannot touch each other, horizontally or vertically.

Comment: What numbers can be used? 1-4? 1-5?

Comment: @npkllr it can be any numbers, say 1-100..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty difficult puzzle! My solution here has a lot of 'usual' deductions left unmentioned.

So first of all, all the 1s can be closed off:

> [image]

Now, there's one cell that must be focused on:

> The top left cell cannot be a 1, so it must extend rightwards. It then cannot be a 2, so the 2 near the top must go down. The same logic can be applied again to get this far:
>
>  [image]

Now, check

> the 2 in the top middle. Can it extend downwards? If it does, then R3C5 must go left to make a size-3 flat region that touches the 3 clue. That's a problem -- so the 2 must go upwards. This forces the top left region to be a 5.
>
>  [image]

Now, an important question appears:

> What's going on in the center? There can't be any 1s in there. There can't be any 2s either. And we can't put a size-3 region in there: so it must be filled by a 4!
>
>  [image]

Now, we can finish the upper right corner, and start on the lower right:

> There must be a single isolated 1 in the upper right, and one of the two potential places is adjacent to an already-existing 1.
>
>  Meanwhile, R5C8 must be a 4, completing a 4 region. This lets us continue down the right-hand side.
>
>  [image]

Now, I make an assumption for sake of contradiction. (This part of the puzzle seems like it should have a 'cleaner' path, but I couldn't find one.)

> Assume that the 3 clue near the center does *not* go down. It must then go left, and then either left or down: either way, the remaining empty cells in column 3 cannot be satisfied. (If left, R6C3 cannot be a 3 or a 1; if down, R8C3 cannot be a 1, 2, or 3, but it only has 3 cells of space to expand into.)
>
>  [image]

This allows us to finish off the bottom right corner

> by realizing that R8C7 must be a 1. Finally, the unresolved 2 clue cannot go right, or R7C4 would be unfillable. This leads to this situation...
>
>  [image]

and the only way to resolve this (completing the puzzle) is

> by an unclued size-5 region.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Exactly right, very well done!