# Spiral Stumper Series: Ripple Effect

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sub>***Spiral Stumper Series*** is a $5$-puzzles series taken from the Final Round of a local (national) contest, [KPK](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86494/28719), which has been ended recently and authored by me. The theme is spiral and each puzzle is standalone (there will be no meta, etc.)</sub>

---

[image]

> **Ripple Effect** (taken from [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/ripple_effect.html))
>
> - The areas divided by bold lines are called "rooms". Fill in all empty cells with numbers under the following rules.
> - Each room contains consecutive numbers starting from 1 (to $n$ where $n$ is the area of the room).
> - If a number is duplicated in a row or a column, the space between the duplicated numbers must be equal to or larger than the value of the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after some hard work (and some luck...)

> [image]

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right, well done! :D