# Spiral Stumper Series: Instructionless Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

<sub>***Spiral Stumper Series*** is a $5$-puzzles series taken from the Final Round of a local (national) contest, [KPK](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86494/28719), which has been ended recently and authored by me. The theme is spiral and each puzzle is standalone (there will be no meta, etc.)</sub>

---

[image]

> **Study the 2 examples given on the left and solve the puzzle on the right!**
>   The solution for each puzzle can be uniquely determined.
>   *(Click the image to enlarge it.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the correct solution, coloured so it's easy to see!

I forgot to do progressive hints. :(

> [image: The solution!]

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the correct answer, well done! :D

Answer (score 10):

The rule is:

> The 1st row and 1st column say how many "PKP" substrings are there in a particular row or column. The 2nd row and 2nd column say how many "KPK" substrings are there in a particular row or column

The full answer table is given below. The black & bold ones were already filled-up in the question :

> [image]

Comment: nice first answer. +1!

Comment: There's a mistake in the 5th column rot13(XCX gjvpr).

Comment: Ah...I must have made some silly mistake...unable to trace it back now without redoing the whole thing completely...

Comment: Welcome to PSE and this is a very nice answer! :D The rule is correct, for the full answer it's actually almost correct: there are only a very few cells need to be changed, see if you could redo it :)